# Pentaho report designer 5 not pulling in MongoDB field list

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

I am able to connect and read the databases and collections from my Mongo instance but when I try to 'Get Fields' I get 'unexpected error'.

I want to pull in the complete field list - Do I need something in the 'Query' tab? ( although tutorials I have watched suggest not)

I have the mongodb driver in ~/lib and ~/lib/jdbc.

I have searched for solution with : 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Caught Kettle Exception:

but no luck.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you may not have your data source properly configured. The details of the Kettle exception would be helpful.

Comment: Check this pentaho and mongo input options http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MongoDB+Input